# How to Rename post in Hexo

Tags: hexo

How can I rename published post in hexo?

Currently, I am deleting existing post and creating the new one by copying contains from an old post.

is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides deleting a post and recreating it as you mentioned, you can also rename the posts filename, title inside of the YAML header, and asset folders.

You can also use the [hexo-console-renamer](https://github.com/timnew/hexo-console-rename) plugin. Using this, change the title of the post inside of the YAML header. Then, run

`hexo rename source/_post/some_post_with_wrong_file_name.md`

Answer (score 1):

1. Rename the post
2. Run `hexo clean`
3. Run `hexo generate`
4. Run `hexo deploy`